# Integrate redux toolkit method createAsyncThunk with Angular HttpClient using ApiService

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to implement `@reduxjs/toolkit` in an Angular application.

How can I pass an Angular service as a param to the callback of `createAsyncThunk` instead of using `fetch`?

Example from the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)

```
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchById',
  async (userId: number) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${userId}`)
    // replace fetch with apiService.fetchUserById(userId)
    return (await response.json()) as MyData
  }
)
```

Eventually I'd like to use `HttpClientModule` to fetch data.

### Edit

This is my approach, is there a better way or a more "Angular way" to implement that?

```
// projects.slice.ts


export const INITIAL_STATE_PROJECTS: IProjectsState = {
    projectList: [],
};

export const fetchProjects = createAsyncThunk(
    'projects/fetchProjects',
    async (projectsService: ProjectsService) => {
        const response = await projectsService.getAllProjects();
        return response;
    }
);

const projectsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'projects',
    initialState: INITIAL_STATE_PROJECTS,
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers: {
        [fetchProjects.fulfilled.toString()]: (state, action) => {
            state.projectList = action.payload;
        },
    }
});

export default projectsSlice.reducer;
```

```
// projects.service.ts


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectsService {
    private serverURL = environment.api_url;
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    async getAllProjects(): Promise<IProject[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            this.http.get<IProject[]>(`${this.serverURL}/projects`, { headers, withCredentials: true })
                .subscribe(async (res) => {
                    resolve(res);
                }, (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

```
// project-list.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'app-project-list',
    templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {
    @select((state: IAppState) => state.projects.projectList) readonly projects$: Observable<any[]>;

    constructor(
        private projectsService: ProjectsService,
        private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.ngRedux.dispatch<any>(fetchProjects(this.projectsService));
    }
}
```

Comment: What hinders you from just using `apiService.getUserById(userId)`?

Comment: I need some way to pass the apiService instance to the callback so that I can invoke `getUserById`.

Comment: Why would you need to pass an instance? Services are generally Singletons in Angular, so there should be only one instance of it in existence.

Comment: I meant that singleton instance. I'm confused cause I implement redux in plane ts files, while the rest of the app use classes. I don't have a way to inject the service so I wonder how can I use HttpClient. Redux docs regards only to react.

Comment: Why are you doing it in a plain js file then?

Comment: Because all the docs examples and tutorials written for js/ts files. No examples for Angular/class implementation. Since I'm not experienced I don't know how to do the conversion for the whole redux configuration end to end.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood this right - if not let me know, but if I did, you could wrap it in an enclosing function:

```
const fetchUserById = (apiService: ApiService, userId: numer) => {
    return createAsyncThunk(
        'users/fetchById',
        async (userId: number) => {
            const response = await apiService.getUserById(userId);
            return (await response.json()) as MyData
        }
    )
}
```

now you can call it like:

```
const user = fetchUserById(apiService, 1);
```

Comment: That's basically what I wanted but it's not the solution, createAsyncThunk need to be assigned to fetchUserById not returned by it. I'll edit my question with more info after I'll do some more research. It is possible that what I asked is not the solution for my issue.